# Communication between modules in R shiny when using shiny.router

Tags: r, shiny, module, reactive

My shiny app is set up so that each page is a separate module that is called by a router when needed. Two of these modules/pages need to communicate between each other so that when users input their username and password on one page, it also fills in on the other page. (Preferably this would be two way but honestly at this point I'll take anything)

Here's a simplified version of the code I am using.

```
#global

headerLinks <<- list(
  #"splash" = "splash",
  "Summary of Recording" = "summary",
  "Indicator Detail" = "detail"
)

routes <- c(
  route("home", pageSplashUI("splash")),
  route("summary", pageSummaryUI("summary")),
  route("detail", pageDetailUI("detail"))
)

router <- make_router(
  routes
)
```

```
shinyUI(
  tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/custom.css")
    ),
    
    router$ui,
    tags$script(src="js/util.js")
  )
)
```

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  moduleControl <- reactiveValues(
    currentPage=NULL,
    moduleMsg=NULL
  )
  
  
  moduleControl$currentPage <- eventReactive(get_page(), {
    get_page()  
  })
  
  pass <- callModule(pageSummary, "summary", "summary", moduleControl)
  callModule(pageDetail, "detail", "detail", moduleControl, pass)
  
  modules <- list(callModule(pageSplash, "home", "splash", moduleControl),
                  callModule(pageDetail, "detail", "detail", moduleControl, pass),
                  callModule(pageSummary, "summary", "summary", moduleControl))
  
  router$server(input,output,session)
})
```

```
pageSummaryUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  createFlexSidebarPage(ns("summary"),
                        createFilterGroup(ns("filters"),
                                          createFilterPanel(ns("DetailUP"),
                                                            "Enter Username and Password",
                                                            textInput(ns("Username"),"Username:"),
                                                            textInput(ns("Password"),"Password:"),
                                                            actionButton(ns("Submit"),"Submit", icon("paper-plane"), 
                                                                         style="color: #fff; background-color: #23356a; border-color: #fff")),
                                          
                                          createFilterPanel(ns("Filters"),
                                                            "Filters",
                                                            selectInput(ns("Ethnicity"), "Ethnicity",
                                                                        choices=unique(data$Prioritised.Ethnicities), selected = "All ethnicities"),
                                                            selectInput(ns("Age"), "Age",
                                                                        choices=unique(data$agegroup), selected = "All ages"),
                                                            selectInput(ns("Year"), "Year",
                                                                        choices=unique(data$year), selected = "All years")
                                          )
                        
                        ),
                        "Summary of Recording",
                        T
  )
}
```

```
pageSummary <- function(input, output, session, name, moduleControl) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  observeEvent(input[["route_summary"]], {
    change_page("summary", session = session)
  })
  
  ### ---- username and password reactivity
  
  passvals <- reactiveValues()
  observe({passvals$pass1 <- input$Password})
  observe({passvals$user1 <- input$Username})
  
  return(passvals)

}
```

```
pageDetailUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  createFlexSidebarPage(ns("detail"),
                        createFilterGroup(ns("filters"),
                                         createFilterPanel(ns("DetailUP"),
                                                            "Enter Username and Password",
                                                            textInput(ns("Username"),"Username:"),
                                                                      textInput(ns("Password"),"Password:"),
                                                                      actionButton(ns("Submit"),"Submit", icon("paper-plane"), 
                                                                                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #23356a; border-color: #fff")),
                                          createFilterPanel(ns("Filters"),
                                                            "Filters",
                                                            selectInput(ns("Indicator"), "Indicator",
                                                                        choices=unique(dfFinal_G24$Indicator)),
                                                            selectInput(ns("Ethnicity"), "Ethnicity",
                                                                        choices=unique(dfFinal_G24$Prioritised.Ethnicities), selected = "All ethnicities"),
                                                            selectInput(ns("Age"), "Age",
                                                                        choices=unique(dfFinal_G24$agegroup), selected = "All ages"),
                                                            selectInput(ns("Year"), "Year",
                                                                        choices=unique(dfFinal_G24$year), selected = "All years")
                                          )
                        
                        ),
                        "Indicator Detail",
                        T
  )
}
```

```
pageDetail <- function(input, output, session, name, moduleControl, pass) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  observeEvent(input[["route_detail"]], {
    change_page("detail", session = session)
  })
  
  ### ---- username and password reactivity
  
  reactive({
    updateTextInput(pageSummary, "Password", value = pass$pass1)
    })

  
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Just checking in if you could resolve this, because I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the module for the page you are switching to in your server and store the session.
2. Use that session in the updateTextInput call.

Comment: I have a separate piece of code that is handling the authentication. Other than that I'm not sure what you're saying I should change, could you clarify?

Comment: Looking at your edited answer I'm still struggling to see what you're saying I should do differently. As far as I can tell my code already has what you're suggesting. Could you write out exactly how/where the code should change?